# Function forgets the trigger? (Google Cloud)

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I created a Google Cloud Function which works like a charm in the Cloud Console. But it wasn't triggered when it should be.

It is a RealTimeDatabase (RTDB) triggered Cloud Function. Then I opened the function again to look for the error, and I saw the path I specified wasn't saved. So I tried again, but it failed again.

---

This is what I'm doing:

[image]

As you see, I have entered the Database name and the Path that is supposed to be the trigger. What I've entered, matches what is shown as an example when I hover over the question mark with my mouse.

Then I click `Save`

[image]

Then I click `Next` and then `Deploy`. Then it takes a few minutes for the function to deploy.

After it was deployed, I open the function again and I see this:

[image]

---

It always completely "forgets" the database I've entered, and it always only saves a part of the path I've specified. I guess this is why the function isn't getting triggered.

But why doesn't the function save what I put in there?

---

So I tried deploying it with gcloud CLI as suggested by Kolban, but I get this error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=5, message=Failed to configure trigger for event-type:providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create resource:projects/_/instances/xxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/refs/user/lukas service:firebaseio.com.`

The code I ran:

`gcloud functions deploy myfunction --entry-point helloRTDB --trigger-event providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.create --trigger-resource projects/_/instances/xxx-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/refs/user/lukas --runtime nodejs16`

**EDIT:**
Okay, so I got it working with gcloud CLI, but the same happened. It's not triggered and when I open the function in the console, it also forgot the database and partly the path

I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Its possible that because this is beta code there may be "issues" with the console.  When I look at the current docs here ... https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database ... it doesn't seem to show the console  as possibiity but instead guides you to use the gcloud CLI.  We might want to try using gcloud and see if it works if we create the Cloud Function definition there.

Comment: I tried that. There's a deploying error, I edited the question and added everything

Comment: Okay, so I got it working with gcloud CLI, but the same happened. It's not triggered and when I open the function in the console, it also forgot the database and partly the path

Comment: @Kolban I can't imagine that it is impossible to deploy cloud functions for RTDB... RTDB exists for so long already. Without cloud functions, it's impossible to build many applications. If you can't deploy a function, even a Beta release doesn't make sense in my eyes

Comment: Sadly I have few skills in Firebase.  Reading here ... https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database I see the flag that this is beta function so there could be lurking things.  Is it the ability to trigger a Cloud Function that is new?

Comment: @LukasNiessen you can file a bug report on this https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs since there are confusion on this in setting up on this.